# Any alternatives for python candas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, can-bus

I have been working the conversion of blf to csv using python candas, but it is taking too long. Can anyone suggest me the best solution.

import candas as cd

db = cd.load_dbc("dbc_folder")

## This is the BLF file 'my_file.blf':

log = cd.from_file("my_file")

## This prints a signal from the messages in the BLF:

print(log["AVGcellTemperature"])

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with candas, but for this simple use case you can convert with python-can in a few lines:

```
import can

with open('trace.blf', 'rb') as f_in:
    log_in = can.io.BLFReader(f_in)

    with open("trace.csv", 'w') as f_out:
        log_out = can.io.CSVWriter(f_out)
        for msg in log_in:
            log_out.on_message_received(msg)
        log_out.stop()
```

Note that the data column is base64 encoded (see the [doc](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/can/io/csv.html)). You can easily turn it in a more conventional format with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from base64 import b64decode

df = pd.read_csv('trace.csv')
df['data'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: b64decode(x).hex())
```

Let us know if you notice any performance improvement!